# How can I render content into an emberjs template that is rendered by the application template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Basically I want to do something like Rails `content_for`, part of a view looks the same everywhere, but some parts of it are different depending on where you are in the site.

Here is an example of what I want: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sikimayo/2/edit

If you run that and check you javascript errors, you will see this error:

```
Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined
```

It seems like `foo-with-outlet` isn't an active view, since it was rendered by the application template, not the current route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal from a perspective of eliminating boilerplate in each sub-route, this can be achieved by nesting outlets and their associated render calls.

See JSBin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sikimayo/4/edit

Comment: This did work, but I would love to see another approach if anyone has any ideas.